# Microsoft Reporting Services. Should I use webservices as a datasource?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-3.5, reporting-services

I have a dilemma.
Here is my set-up:
ASP.NET/NET 3.5 web application build using standards(DB layers, BL layers, etc...)

I need to generate some reports. Standard way of doing that is to have reporting service query database directly OR I can have reporting services query web services(which I will create).

I like web services approach because if underlying schema changes, I only need to make sure that my web services return correct data. Reporting services are not affected.

If using direct query to the database, reporting services need to be updated.

**Should I use web services(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129(SQL.90).aspx) or direct queries?**

Comment: I'd say direct query for sake of performance.

Comment: my goal is to make changes in one place. with webservices, I only have to make sure that web service returns correct data and not worry about reporting services ever. For example, simple column rename in the database will force me to go to the reporting services and change the query, whereas with webservices I don't have to worry about it. Now, what if it is a more complex change than a column rename?

Comment: OData would be a good fit if you can wait for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better approach would be (if possible) to use services as your API for both (application and reporting services).  That would keep the code/logic in a central spot as well as accomplish your goals on the reporting services.

Answer (score 2):

Using a web service makes maintenance easier. The performance will suffer some but to what extent is relative to your hardware, database design, queries, etc... I would use the web service as this is the way Adobe Flex applications are suppose to do it and Microsoft WCF seems to be pointing DotNet developers in the direction of web service data sources.

Another benefit is that you can use multiple clients with the same service.